# SQL raisserror not showing

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I'm trying to execute a sproc but I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction. When my IF conditions are true it will not print my raiseerrors...

```
 set transaction isolation level repeatable read 

 declare @return_value int = 0  
 declare @someValue int = 3
 SET @retry = 3;


 --Keep trying to update 
 --table if this task is 
 --selected as the deadlock 
 --victim.
 WHILE (@retry > 0)
 BEGIN
 BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    --check someValue
    if @someValue < 5 
        begin
            raiserror ('number is less than 5', 16,1)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            return 99               
        end

    --all o.k , set retry 0 ending the while, commit transaction--                                                          
    SET @retry = 0;                
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;            
 END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
    RAISERROR ('Errors found, please fix these errors and retry. Transaction     Rolled back', 16, 2);
    -- Check error number.
    -- If deadlock victim error,
    -- then reduce retry count
    -- for next update retry. 
    -- If some other error
    -- occurred, then exit
    -- retry WHILE loop.
    IF (ERROR_NUMBER() = 1205)
        SET @retry = @retry - 1;
    ELSE
        SET @retry = -1;  
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
 END CATCH;
 END; -- End WHILE loop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `RaIsError` will be consumed by the catch block. If you want to preserve it, and perhaps add additional information, you can do something like this:

```
set xact_abort, nocount on;
set transaction isolation level repeatable read; -- Scope is this stored procedure.
declare @LocalTransaction as Bit = case when @@TranCount = 0 then 1 else 0 end;

declare @Return_Value as Int = 0;
declare @SomeValue int = 3;
declare @Retry as Int = 3;

while @Retry > 0
begin
    begin try
        if @LocalTransaction = 1
            begin transaction;

        if @SomeValue < 5
            RaIsError ( 'Number is less than 5.', 16, 1 );

        set @Retry = 0;
        if @LocalTransaction = 1
            commit transaction;
    end try
    begin catch
        if Error_Number() = 1205
            set @Retry -= 1;
        else
        begin
            set @Retry = -1;
            -- Save the exception.
            declare @ErrorLine as Int = Error_Line();
            declare @ErrorMessage as NVarChar(4000) = Error_Message();
            declare @ErrorNumber as Int = Error_Number();
            declare @ErrorProcedure as NVarChar(126) = Error_Procedure();
            declare @ErrorSeverity as Int = Error_Severity();
            declare @ErrorState as Int = Error_State();
            declare @NewLine as Char(2) = Char( 13 ) + Char( 10 ); -- '\r\n'.

            -- Rollback only transactions when there is an active transaction that we started.
            if Xact_State() <> 0 and @LocalTransaction = 1
                rollback transaction;

            -- Exit with the exception.
            RaIsError( '%s%s#%i [Proc: %s/Line %i]', @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState, @ErrorMessage, @NewLine, @ErrorNumber, @ErrorProcedure, @ErrorLine );
            return 99;
        end;
    end catch;
end;
```

Note that the error return is also handled by the catch block since code in the try block after the RaIsError shouldn't execute.